# How can the type of SQL query parameter be controlled when using a string property in .NET Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

On the database table there is a column of type `char(2)`.

When I use a parameter in linq such as `.Where(x => x.Code == code)` the SQL query parameter is translated into `varchar(max)` where I would really like it to be `char(2)` in order to avoid an implicit conversion. This is because the query is not using the indexes of the database in the way that I would like.

```
Property(c => c.Code)
            .HasColumnType("char")
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(2);
```

The code first mapping is shown above. The only thing that seems to affect the translation is the `.HasColumnType("char")` It doesn't seem to affect the query translation, as that influences whether it picks a `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`.

I have thought of two solutions, one is to get the database changed so that it uses an `int` and a lookup instead of the char code, the other is to convert the code to use an expression. Two things I'd rather not do, if there is a better way to control the mappings to sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a way to achieve this.

Instead of using `.Where(x => x.Code = code)`

I am now using

```
var codes = new string[] { code }
```

...

```
.Where(x => codes.Contains(x.Code))
```

This translates into a constant in the query rather than a parameter.